# Find file in nested folder and dynamically import the file as a module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, relative-path, import-module

Lets say I have a file structure as follows:

```
folder1
  --file1.py

  folderStart
    --start.py

  folder2
    --file2.py

  folderX
    --fileX.py
  ...
```

In start.py, I get a name of a file dynamically, for example:
`file_name = "file3"`

I dont know where the "file3" is, as I dont get the file path with it. It could be anywhere in folder1 or a subfolder: folder2, folderX etc.
I then need to dynamically import the "file3" and for that I need to know its relative path to start.py.

```
import_module(f"{file_path}")
```

How do I find the "file3" and its path so I can call the import?

Thanks for any replies, I am a beginner so sorry if unclear. Tried getting the relative path unsuccessfully

**Edit: All files and folders have random names, unsorted
Also, theres a file structure above folder1 and I only need to look inside folder1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try glob.glob("**/**file3.py", recursive=True)

Comment: If your files are sorted (they look sorted), you can do binary search combined with [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) package. This is better than the previous answer by @lotus because it does not brute force search.

Comment: @rkochar i dont think this is a great idea since the order of files is operating system dependent and if you would sort the beforehand the time complexity would be higher

Comment: @rkochar They are not sorted unfortunately

Comment: @lotus this throws -- TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '../file3

Comment: @lotus you don't need to sort the folders, they already have a number at the end :). You only need to check if folder exists, and if it does, a single pass of the files in the folder to determine the direction of next search.

Comment: @rkochar Could you pleaaaase show me how the binary search combined with os package would look. Pretty pleaaase.

Comment: @JohnDoe [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) has methods to access the file system. You can use it to check if a file exists for instance. This describes [binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/). You would first use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to get all folders. Pick the middle folder (between 1 and X in your example) and do a simple binary search.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

````
import os
def find_file(root_folder, target_file):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
        if target_file in files:
            return os.path.join(root, target_file)
    return None

root_folder = '/path/to/unknown/root/folder'
target_file = 'file_name.txt'

file_path = find_file(root_folder, target_file)

if file_path:
    print(f"File '{target_file}' found at: {file_path}")
else:
    print(f"File '{target_file}' not found in the specified folder.")```
````

Comment: Thank you, is this better than glob as suggested above?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).